# how to install phonegap for visual studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova

I'm completed new to phonegap and now I want to develop an app on my phone(android) through phonegap and using visual studio 2013 as an editor. I searched online and the tutorial told me that I only need to download the zip file of phonegap and then copy and paste to the project template. I did that, but after that I didn't see phonegap pop up as the tutorial said when I start the new project in VS 2013. I was wondering that did I miss something? Do I need to also download and install the android SDK first ? The zip file I download was called 'phonegap-2.9.1.zip', and I downloaded it from the official website of phonegap.

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup cordova using NPM (node package manager). Install node.js (http://nodejs.org/) to use npm for package manager. If you not install node.js, you should not be able to invoke node or npm on your command line to install cordova apache. Then install cordova apache using CLI.

Type this command to install cordova apache.

If you can’t install, make sure you run the command prompt as administrator.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

After you finish install the cordova apache. You can start create your project using cordova command. Open your terminal/command prompt, type these command. You can ignore sudo if you using Windows.

```
cordova create YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
```

Open config.xml inside cordova project that you already created just now. Change id and name. Others are optional.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="YOUR_PROJECT_NAME" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>YOUR_PROJECT_NAME</name>
    <description>
        YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.
    </description>
    <author email="mohammadnrdn@gmail.com" href="http://revivalx.com">
        Mohammad Nurdin bin Norazan
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Go back to terminal and add platform for windows mobile. Type these command to add wp8 platforms.

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

Then you can import this project inside your visual studio 2013.

For more details: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/02/develop-a-simple-to-do-list-mobile-app-using-phonegapcordova-for-ios-and-android-part-1/

Comment: Thank you, following ur instruction I could use the phone gap now.